# Displaying online chat users in signalr. It adds users to the list, but does not remove them

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to build a very simple chat application in `MVC5` using `SignalR`.

I created a list of strings in my hub class and two simple methods to add and remove elements, call clients to display the list of users via `Jquery`.

Adding users works fine, however it does not remove them from the list. Any idea why?

```
static List<string> users = new List<string>();

    public void AddUser(string name)
    {
        if (!users.Contains(name))
        {
            users.Add(name);
            Clients.All.updateUserList(users);
        }
        Clients.All.updateUserList(users);
    }
    public void RemoveUser(string name)
    {
        if (users.Contains(name))
        {
            users.Remove(name);
            Clients.All.updateUserList(users);
        }
        Clients.All.updateUserList(users);
    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {            
        Clients.Caller.connected();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnReconnected()
    {            
        Clients.Caller.connected();
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {            
        Clients.Caller.disconnected();
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

In the view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.ChatHub;  

        chat.client.updateUserList = function (users) {
            var userList = $("#nameUsers");
            userList.empty();
            $.each(users, function (i) {
                var li = $('<li/>')
                    .text(users[i])
                    .appendTo(userList);                    
            });
        };

        chat.client.connected = function () {
            chat.server.addUser("@ViewBag.Username");
        };

        chat.client.disconnected = function () {
            chat.server.removeUser("@ViewBag.Username");
        }; ....
```

I get the username from the `MVC` controller in a `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 1):

The remove logic should take place on the `OnDisconnected` method.
[Read this article from the SignalR documentation that explains lifetime events.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

The idea is that your client doesn't get to call the `removeUser` method because it has already disconnected from the server.

So SignalR implemented the `OnDisconnected` method (you override it, add your logic and then return `base.OnDisconnected`) and you let the server determine the disconnection time.

Best of luck!

Comment: Radu thanks for your quick response. I have updated my question. Is this what you meant? I did not include `OnDisconnected` because I thought it was obvious that is what I am using to call it as it is also in the `View`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers - once the client is disconnected - it cannot invoke remove users on the server. A better solution would be:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> users = new List<string, string>();

private void AddUser(string connectionId, string name)
{
    lock (users)
    {
        users[connectionId] = name;
        Clients.All.updateUserList(users.Values.Distinct());
    }
}
private void RemoveUser(string connectionId)
{
    lock (users)
    {
        users.Remove(connectionId);
        Clients.All.updateUserList(users.Values.Distinct());
    }
}
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{            
    AddUser(Context.ConnectionId, User.Identity.Name);
    return base.OnConnected();
}
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnReconnected()
{            
    AddUser(Context.ConnectionId, User.Identity.Name);
    return base.OnReconnected();
}
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{            
    RemoveUser(Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

Key differences:

1. Avoid trusting the client invocation of the server hub methods - you get into all sorts of problems then... from network issues, to someone potentially trying to sabotage your system
2. Locking around the users objection - without locking you could get corruption
3. Keying the user by the connectionId, not the username - this allows for a user to be using two separate browsers/tabs and not screwing up things (in previous code, try logging in on two tabs, then closing one will look like both users have logged off).

Your next problem is the user of statics (which is a bit of a hack), but that's a minor issue by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection is lost while removing user.You have to establish connection.

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        console.log("Disconnected. Reason: " + $.connection.hub.lastError.message); 
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });

It will reestablish your connection.
```